# Cant upload android SDK revision 22

Tags: android

I download android SDK and ADV manager, try download android SDK revision 22 and android SDK revision 19. Log:

```
Skipping 'Android SDK Tools, revision 22'; it depends on 'Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19' which was not installed.
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19
Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19
'adb kill-server' succeeded.
ADB: daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 
ADB: daemon started successfully 
'adb start-server' succeeded.
```

And nothing. Nothing was uploaded. I install and launch android SDK and ADV manager as administrator and using compalibity mode Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling android sdk or try updating it agin.
This error can happen due to wrong update order (it tries updating sdk first, not it's depedency).